# Transfer basic yii2 application on a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, yii2, webdeploy

I already had an EC2 instance on Amazon (AWS) and a basic yii2 application.

The following were already setup on EC2 Instance:

```
PHP
Postgresql
Apache2
```

Now, I want to transfer the yii2 application on EC2 Instance?
Does anyone know the process on how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It all depends on you, you have multiple solutions to do this, from copying files by FTP (which is really really bad practise) to configuring auto-deployment (like AWS CodeDeploy).

Comment: Can you suggest some solutions? please.

Comment: Like i said, solution depends on you and your environment. If you want to get some examples, you can just google it, like: [here](https://stackify.com/software-deployment-tools/)